# What should a dockerfile contain to run a simple CRUD web application?

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, docker, dockerfile

I am studying Docker and to understand better, I want to use it to run a Java web application that I created a while ago. It uses Java, Spring, Hibernate on back-end and Spring MVC on front-end, and MySQL as a database. In Eclipse, it can be easily run on Tomcat and opened in a browser. In essence, it's a simple CRUD application.

In order to create a dockerfile to run it, do I need to start with (FROM) an OS image? How do I include Java, MySQL and Tomcat instances? How can I configure it to run the application war?

Comment: I would recommend that you watch these videos on the docker site https://training.docker.com/self-paced-training. I also found the following training material useful http://view.dckr.info:9090/#1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard Docker style is to have a single service per container and then have an orchestration tool manage the containers as a group.

Docker comes with a tool called [Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) that is configured with a `docker-compose.yml` file.

```
version: '2'

services:
  myapp_web:
    build: ./web/
    ports:
     - "8080:8080"
    networks:
     - myapp_net

  myapp_db:
    build: ./db/
    volumes:
     - myapp_data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
     - myapp_net

volumes:
  myapp_data:

networks:
  myapp_net:
    driver: bridge
```

#### Dockerfile

It will be easiest if you start your Dockerfiles from existing images so you don't have to deal with complete builds. Most popular open source software will have images available on [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/). Searching " docker" will normally be the top result. Have a look at the `Dockerfile` from the images you use. The official images tend to use all the current best practices.

The [`mysql` image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/) gives you a blank mysql installation with some custom configuration options. You might not need a `Dockerfile` here initially.

`./db/Dockerfile`

```
FROM mysql:5.7
RUN some-setup.sh
```

The [`tomcat` image](https://hub.docker.com/_/tomcat/) supplies a working OpenJDK and Tomcat installation for you to deploy your app to.

`./web/Dockerfile`

```
FROM 8.0-jre8-alpine
COPY myapp.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/myapp.war
```